# pylearn2's show_weights.py: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_weights_view'

Tags: python, machine-learning

**edit**: The bug was resolved in [PR 1012](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/pull/1012).

---

I'm having trouble running `show_weights.py cifar_grbm_smd.pkl` in [step 3 of the quick start tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/tutorial/index.html#step-3-inspect-the-model), which returns:

```
... in weights_view = dataset.get_weights_view(W)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_weights_view'
```

However, `plot_monitor.py cifar_grbm_smd.pkl` works just fine. Both `show_weights.py` and `plot_monitor.py` work in `pylearn2/scripts/tutorials/dbm_demo/train_dbm.py`.

I inspected the attributes of the pickled objects (dbm.pkl and cifar_grbm_smd.pkl) and determined that it had, among others, the following:

- .get_weights
- .get_weights_format
- .get_weights_topo
- .get_weights_view_shape

Thus, I saw no `get_weights_view`. Which would explain why the quick start tutorial failed. But why would the other test work, and why would the tutorial be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer who introduced the bug should have corrected it in [this pull request](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/pull/1012).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the file get_weights_report.py is missing a line. Try adding the following two lines:

```
        dataset_filename = yaml_parse.load(model.dataset_yaml_src)
        dataset = serial.load(dataset_filename)
```

in the section

```
    if dataset is None:
        logger.info('loading dataset...')
        control.push_load_data(False)
        dataset_filename = yaml_parse.load(model.dataset_yaml_src)
        dataset = serial.load(dataset_filename)
        control.pop_load_data()
        logger.info('...done')
```

around line 111.  Basically in the current version dataset is the name of the pickled file rather than its contents.

Comment: A great first post! Welcome to StackOverflow. Live long and prosper.